# chef couldn't find HOME environment -- expanding `~'

Tags: chef-infra, cookbook

When my chef-client runs in intervals it raises this error and just quits without syncing any cookbooks. But it work in my prompt if I manually invoke it. Any idea how to fix it?

```
[2014-02-26T11:58:12+00:00] INFO: Forking chef instance to converge...
[2014-02-26T11:58:12+00:00] INFO: *** Chef 11.10.4 ***
[2014-02-26T11:58:12+00:00] INFO: Chef-client pid: 7880
[2014-02-26T11:58:13+00:00] INFO: Run List is [role[TestingRolesAs_Main]]
[2014-02-26T11:58:13+00:00] INFO: Run List expands to [some cookbooks here, chef-client]
[2014-02-26T11:58:13+00:00] INFO: Starting Chef Run for 
[2014-02-26T11:58:13+00:00] INFO: Running start handlers
[2014-02-26T11:58:13+00:00] INFO: Start handlers complete.
[2014-02-26T11:58:13+00:00] INFO: HTTP Request Returned 404 Object Not Found: 
[2014-02-26T11:58:13+00:00] INFO: Loading cookbooks [chef-client, cron, listpackages, logrotate, s247agentinstall, s247cleanup, servermonitoragent]
[2014-02-26T11:58:13+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[2014-02-26T11:58:13+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2014-02-26T11:58:13+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2014-02-26T11:58:13+00:00] ERROR: couldn't find HOME environment -- expanding `~'
[2014-02-26T11:58:13+00:00] ERROR: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
[2014-02-26T11:58:13+00:00] ERROR: Sleeping for 300 seconds before trying again
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some path set to `~/something` somewhere in your cookbooks.

When Chef runs as a daemon, it does so with a minimal shell environment, where the `HOME` variable is probably not set, so it fails to expand `~`.